# What's the shortcut to interrupt the kernel in Canopy?

Tags: macos, kernel, interrupt, shortcut, canopy

I'm on OSX, using canopy. Does anybody know what the shortcut for interrupting the kernel is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut for interrupting the kernel. That command, along with restarting the kernel, is in the Run menu, which also shows the shortcut for the restart kernel command. Note that because of the nature of the interaction between Python and C extensions, neither command is guaranteed to work, though restart is more likely to in a pinch.